# Invalid query executed in @Transactional method and throws "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have table MySQL table `homeworks` that has custom `id` - I need to generate it myself and set it in the constructor, and in table `students` ID is generated and I don't set it. I have a many-to-one unidirectional relationship between students and homeworks because table `students` exists for a while so I don't want to add new fields to `students` while table `homeworks` is newly created.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "homeworks")
public class Homework {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "homework_id")
    String id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
    Student student;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    String data;

    public Homework(String id, Long studentId, String data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.student = new Student(studentId);
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @NotNull
    String address;

    ... other fields, no relation to `Homework`

    public Student(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I work with repository that extends `JpaRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface HomeworkRepository extends JpaRepository<Homework, String> {
    void deleteByStudentId(Long studentId);
}
```

I have method that removes all `homeworks` by field `student_id` and then inserts one new `homework`:

```
@Transactional
public HomeworkResult pass(Student student, String homeworkData) {

    // some other logic
    String newHomeworkId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();  // it's supposed to be pretty random

    HomeworkResult homeworkResult = new HomeworkResult(data);  // this is some other helper class, not a table

    this.homeworkRepository.deleteByStudentId(student.getId());
    this.homeworkRepository.save(new Homework(newHomeworkId, student.getId(), homeworkData));

    // return non-entity class
    return homeworkResult;
}
```

But somewhere in the method (exact line is not shown in stacktrace - I guess because of `@Transactional`) an error happens:
`Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from homeworks where homework_id=?`

I don't understand why something is deleted by `homework_id`? Is it hidden logic related to JPA or `@Transactional`?

I don't get this error every time when I call this method, maybe the exception is thrown when the load gets higher? but why is it thrown?

I tried to remove `@Transactional` and the method didn't work at all.

Comment: the error message is quite clear. Apparently, the record you are trying to update doesn't exist. Which seems logical, since you delete it, before you try to update it. Remove the delete, and try again.

Comment: or the problem might be because you generate the homeworkId, and then try to execute an update.

Comment: by any chance, is the new homework id the same as the deleted one or not? Also, how is your `Homework` constructor working, since the field is of type student but you actually pass the id only

Comment: @Stultuske what do you mean by `execute an update`? do delete+save in same Transactional method work as update? then how do I delete all `homeworks` and then insert a new one, in two separate Transactional methods? I don't need to _update_ any homework ever

Comment: @SvetlanaGuma read the error message you get: "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update" you seem to be executing an update, but for an id that isn't known.

Comment: @PaulD I have updated the question: `homeworkId` is generated from, for example, UUID, and the `studentId` is provided to `public Student(Long id) { ... }` constructor

Comment: maybe you need to recreate the tables because you started before with another domain class where the mapping was wrong

Comment: @user39950 `homeworks` table is new from scratch, `students` exists for a while, that's why the relation is unidirectional - I didn't want to change anything in `students`

Comment: try to recreate all in a new database and see if the issue persists